# Cyclic group mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $7,$ that is, $G$ consists of all $a^i$, where $a^7 = e.$ Why is the mapping $\phi:a^i\to a^{2i}$ an automorphism of $G$ of order $3$?

I know the group $G$ is formed by the elemets $\{ e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5, a^6 \}$. Now under the mapping $\phi$, the order of elements is changed to: $e, a^2, a^4, a^6, a, a^3, a^5 $. Thus, $\phi$ is both one-one and onto. What I don't understand is why $G$ is of order $3$ by the map $\phi$?

Comment: Before posting a Question, please read definitions of the terms which you want to use in your post...

Comment: The ordering of the elements is not the matter. I think you dont understand the term "$\phi$ is an automorphism". When a map $\phi$ from $G$ to $G$ is called an automorphism?

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang An automorphism is defined to be an isomorphism that is onto therefore it maps a group $G$ onto itself.

Comment: @user104235 Nice. What about isomorphism?

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang Isomorphism is a homomorphism that is one to one.

Comment: @user104235 one to one mean bijective( that is one-one and onto).

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang My book has a different definition. It doesn't say it is bijective instead it says it is one-one.

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang This is what my book says, "A homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ into $\bar{G}$ is said to be an isomorphism if $\phi$ is one-to-one.

Comment: My suggestion to you is that you should clear with all the definitions. Understand them properly. Then it will not be difficult for you to understand the answer that i have post. Best of lucks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\phi^3(a^i) = a^{8i} = a^i$, since $8i \equiv i {\rm mod} 7$ and $\phi^2(a^i) = a^{4i} \neq a^i$.

Comment: I still don't understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: Which part you dont understand?

Comment: How they got order 3 from the map?

Comment: Do you understand by term "order of $\phi$"?

Comment: No, I don't think I do.

Comment: $\phi$ is an element of the group $Aut(G)$, the group of all automorphism of $G$. So order of $\phi$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\phi^n = I$, where $I$ is the identity map, that is $I(g) = g$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: How is $\phi$ an element? Isn't $\phi$ defined as a mapping?

Comment: It is an element of $Aut(G)$ and also at the same time a mapping from $G$ to $G$.

Comment: How would I do this using a different method then the one you used because I don't think I have been taught that yet.

Comment: New answers will not help, unless you understand the definition of " order of $\phi$", that is understanding the question itself. Tell me if you dont understanding this definition of "order of $\phi$". 3 is called an order of $\phi$ if $\phi(\phi(\phi(g)))=g$ for all $g \in G$ and $\phi(h)\neq h$, $\phi(\phi(h)) \neq h$ for some $h\in G$.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of order of $\phi$. Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Let me try and explain what I don't understand. 

The group G is $\{ e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5, a^6 \}$ 

Under $\phi$, the order of elements is changed to : $e, a^2, a^4, a^6, a, a^3, a^5 $. Hence, $\phi$ is both one-one and onto. What I don't understand is where did $\phi^3$ come from? Why did you choose $3$?

Comment: You need to understand the meaning of "order of an element $g$ of a group $G$" (you will find this in any group theory text book and try to find order of the elements of the group $\mathbb Z_6$). After that  you have to prove that $Aut(G)$, the set of all automorphism of $G$, form a group, under the composition of mapping (The identity map is the identity element of $Aut(G)$). $\phi$ is an element of $Aut(G)$, so it has an order ( since every element of a group has an order). $\phi^3$ means $\phi \circ \phi \circ \phi$. Please do a little bit of work. Tell me if you still dont understand.

Comment: I do understand the order of an element $g$ of a group $G$. It is the element that generates the function thus $a^i = e$ where $e$ is the identity. And the order of the automorphism, $n$, is the smallest number such that $\phi^n$ is the identity automorphism but how did they figure out that $\phi^3 = e$? I did $\phi$ but how can I do $\phi^3$? I did $\phi^2$ which gave me $\phi^2 = \{e,a,a^2,a^4,a^5,a^6\}$ and $\phi^3$ generate the group. Is that how they got $\phi^3$?